# Icalendar set full day event

Tags: python, set, icalendar

Good morning, I would like to create an event that lasts all day, without it appearing time from 00.00 to 00.00, I searched the internet but I can not make it visulize correctly... Thank you

```
            def ics_free():
                event = Event()
                event['uid'] = f'19970610T172345Z-AF23B2@{dayclnd}{monthclnd}{yearclnd}'
                event.add('summary', f'{tagesinfo}')
                event.add('description', f'{tagesinfo}')
                event.add('dtstart', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd))
                event.add('dtend', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd))
                event.add('dtstamp', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd))
                event.add('priority', 5)
                event.allday = True
                organizer = vCalAddress(f'MAILTO:{receiver_email}')
                organizer.params['cn'] = vText(f'{username} Monatsplan')
                organizer.params['role'] = vText(f'{username} Monatsplan')
                event.add('priority', 5)
                # Adding events to calendar
                cal.add_component(event)
            ics_free()
```

Comment: An ‘all day’ event is flagged as starting at the beginning of one day and lasting until the beginning of the next:

    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20020923
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20020924

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dates and add a day to the end date

```py
event.add('dtstart', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd).date())
event.add('dtend', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd).date() + timedelta(days=1))
```